# Numpy bivariate normal distribution with correlation = 1

Tags: numpy, normal-distribution

Consider X and Y to be marginally standard normal with correlation 1.0.

When the correlation is 1.0, the bivariate normal distribution is undefined (it's technically the y = x line), but numpy still prints out values. Why does it do this?

Comment: Hi, was your question answered? If so, could you please accept and upvote the answer? If not, what can be clarified?

Answer (score 1):

Oh, but the distribution is defined! It just doesn't have a well-defined *density* function. (At least, not with respect to the Lesbegue measure on the 2D space.) (See [Mathematics Stack Exchange's discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98801/probability-distribution-function-that-does-not-have-a-density-function) on broader groups of such distributions.) So `numpy` is doing nothing wrong.

What you're describing is the [degenerate case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Degenerate_case) of the bivariate (or more generally, multivariate) normal distribution. This occurs when the covariance matrix is not positive definite. However, the distribution is defined for any positive *semi*-definite covariance matrix.

As an example, the matrix [[1, 1], [1, 1]] [is positive not definite](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=is%20%7B%7B1%2C%201%7D%2C%20%7B1%2C%201%7D%7D%20positive%20definite%3F) but [is positive semidefinite](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=is%20%7B%7B1%2C%201%7D%2C%20%7B1%2C%201%7D%7D%20positive%20semi-definite%3F).

The distribution still has a host of other properties that distributions should: a support (the real line, as you note: *μ + span(Σ)*), moments, and more.

```
import numpy as np

np.random.multivariate_normal(mean=[0, 0], cov=[[1, 1], [1, 1]])
# array([0.61156886, 0.61156887])
```

In summary, `numpy`'s behavior isn't broken. It's well-behaved by returning samples from a properly specified distribution.